# How to round a float without a built-in function (C)?

Tags: rounding

I have a function that calculates the average of all elements in an array. It should output a rounded (to the nearest integer) average. How can I round the float value of the average without using the round() function?

Thanks.

The variable 'avg' is defined as float. I tried avg = int(avg) but this method simply dismisses whatever is after the decimal point.

Comment: What's wrong with `#round`?

Comment: `(int)(avg+0.5)` ?

Comment: ... or `(int)((avg >= 0.0 ) ? avg+0.5 : avg-0.5)` if negative values must be covered.

Comment: @nielsen Using (int)(avg+0.5) yields the same result. For example, if avg = 3.6, then (int)(avg+0.5) returns 3 instead of 4.

Comment: @Yonathan In that case there is another problem. If `avg` is a float with value 3.6, then `(int)(avg+0.5)` does return 4. Try `float f=3.6; printf("%d", (int)(f+0.5));`.

Comment: @nielsen Thank you, your suggestion worked, I had an issue in a previous line in the code.